# Как сделать разные статические папки для роутов с помошью express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, express

У меня есть на сервере две middleware такого типа.

```
app.use('/', client);
app.use('/render', server);
```

как мне указать в роутах, что бы для каждой middleware использовались разные статические папки ?

middleware client:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('client');
});
```

middleware server:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(`${__dirname}/dist`)));

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('server');
});
```

Я так сделал но статические файлы не видит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [serve-static](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html).

Так подключайте:

```
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public-optimized')))
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Comment: Спасибо я с этим разобрался. не поскажете у меня есть строка на сервере '<script>console.log('some function')</script>' как мне её вставить в документ что бы функция выполнилась ?

Comment: задайте отдельно вопрос, я не очень понял, что вы имеете в виду. При рендере страницы ваш скрипт выполнится.

Comment: Сделал отдельный вопрос
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998928/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java-script