# Как выполнить скрипт на странице из строки в java script?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, веб-программирование, компоненты

Для серверного рендеринга web components, мне надо что бы у меня выполнился скрипт на странице.
Если я делаю запрос на сервер и получаю ответ строка читается хорошо, но когда я делаю fetch запрос на сервер, что бы уже на существующей странице добавить компонент ответ я получаю но не знаю как выполнить скрипт.

Упрощённо, строка для рендеринга выгляди так:

```
`<script>function __ssr(){console.log('exprestion')}> 
 <script>__ssr()</script>`
```

реальная строка:

```
 `<script>function __ssr(){var a=document.currentScript.previousElementSibling,b=a.firstElementChild;a.removeChild(b);for(var c=a.attachShadow({mode:"open"});b.hasChildNodes();)c.appendChild(b.firstChild);}</script><x-hello><shadow-root><span>Hello, <x-yell><shadow-root><strong><slot></slot></strong></shadow-root><slot></slot></x-yell><script>__ssr()</script>!</span></shadow-root>World</x-hello><script>__ssr()</script>`
```

Как получив fetch запросом эту строку с сервера выполнить на странице для рендеринга веб компонента ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по упрощенному примеру проще всего слать js сразу и выполнять его с помощью `eval`, без оборачивания в теги скрипт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо экранировать `/` -> `\/`, так это даже в сниппет не лезет, однако если это приходит с сервера можно сделать это регуляркой.

а дальше просто присоединить к странице

```js
let str = '<script>function __ssr(){var a=document.currentScript.previousElementSibling,b=a.firstElementChild;a.removeChild(b);for(var c=a.attachShadow({mode:"open"});b.hasChildNodes();)c.appendChild(b.firstChild);}<\/script><x-hello><shadow-root><span>Hello, <x-yell><shadow-root><strong><slot><\/slot><\/strong><\/shadow-root><slot><\/slot><\/x-yell><script>__ssr()<\/script>!<\/span><\/shadow-root>World<\/x-hello><script>__ssr()<\/script>'; 


setTimeout(e => $('body').append(str), 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1234
```

PS:  через `eval` можно было бы если только скрипт приезжал, но у Вас там разметка...

Comment: Может быть не правильно про разметку понял.Через час тестировать буду. Если это про css не думаю что помешает. У меня в shadowRoot  основная структура в document['body'] а компоненты, которые приходят, подключаются слотами, по этому разметка слотов всегда на всю ширину экрана у самих компонентов. Мне интереснее смогу я на сервере скрипты запустить или нет, которые у меня в компонентах. В hadless chrome хорошо всё работает, но здесь вариант более компактный, но ещё не знаю какие ограничения у него есть.

Comment: В дополнение к вопросу и о стилях картинку прикрепил со структурой.